# Access parent window's 'window' object from child window - Electron

Tags: electron, multi-window, electron-window

Is there any way to access the parent window's **window** object from the child windows. I want to duplicate the content in the parent window to the child windows with a single remote connection for all windows.

Comment: did you set the `parent` property on the `BrowserWindow` class when creating the child window ?

Comment: yes. I did. But I didn't find a way to access clone the parent window. The application itself has a connection with a remote API which is updating real time. I want to clone the application windows without establishing multiple connections.

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetparentwindow